# creating a cascading dropbox in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested object that I'm trying to turn into a cascading select box.

```
    "A": {
      "a1": 1,
      "a2": 2
    },
    "B": {
      "b1": {
        "b11": 111
      },
      "b2": {
        "b222": 222
      }
    }
  };
```

The user should select values until he reachs a value. The depth of the collection is unknown.

For example - `"B"` -> `"b1"` -> `"b11"` -> `111`. in this case we have three select boxes. `"A"` -> `"a1"` -> `1` - only two. Each box will appear after a value is selected in the previous level.

I tried it with a template (from what i red this is the only way to implement recursion). I need the final value at `scope.value`.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="cascading_combo.html">
    <h5> current </h5>
    <pre>{{current | json}}</pre>
    <select ng-model='value' ng-options="v as k for (k,v) in current"></select>
    <pre> type of {{value}} : {{angular.isObject(value)}}</pre>
    <span ng-if="angular.isObject(value)" ng-init='current=value' ng-include='"cascading_combo.html"'>
    </span>
</script>
```

This is not working, partialy because `angular.isObject` is not returning any result.

[JSBIN playgorund.](http://jsbin.com/IKuHAga/1/edit)

Angular newbi, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `angular.isObject()` in an expression like that. What Angular then is looking for is the function `$scope.angular.isObject()` in the scope of the parent controller (just as `value` really is `$scope.value`).

What you can do is this:

In `selectCtrl`:

```js
$scope.isObject = angular.isObject;
```

In `cascading_combo.html`:

```html
<pre> type of {{value}} : {{isObject(value)}}</pre>
<span ng-if="isObject(value)" ng-init='current=value' ng-include='"cascading_combo.html"'>
```

**Problem**: You run into an infinite loop.

If `value` is an object, the template is loaded again. All these templates exist in the same scope of `selectCtrl` so when the new template is appended `value` is *still* an object so *another* template is appended and so on...

To prevent this you have to reset `value` when a new template is appended. For example you can modify your template again and do this:

```html
<select ng-init="value=undefined" ng-model="value" ng-options="k for (k,v) in current"></select>
```

See [here](http://jsbin.com/IKuHAga/4/edit) for the final result.

---

## Update

The example above doesn't work in a dynamic way since a template can't be removed once it's added. Here is a non-recoursive approach using `ngRepeat` and a single list:

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div recoursive-select="" ng-repeat="item in selected"></div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selected = [/** insert first element here **/];
});

app.directive('recoursiveSelect', function() {
    return {
        template: '<select ng-model="newSelected" ng-options="key for (key, value) in data"></select>',
        controller: function($scope) {
            // workaround to strip the $$hashKey of ngRepeat
            $scope.data = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson($scope.item));
            // watch for selecting a value
            $scope.$watch('newSelected', function(newSelected) {
                // watch is always called initially. do this to prevent infinite loop
                if (!newSelected) return;
                var nextIndex = $scope.$index + 1;
                // remove all "deeper" elements plus the one on this level
                while ($scope.selected.length > nextIndex) {
                    $scope.selected.pop()
                }
                // add the newly selected element on this level
                $scope.selected.push(newSelected);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[live](http://jsfiddle.net/U4d7p/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Mouagip. If you choose A then a1,a2 appear, But if you change your first selection to B - nothing is happening. Is it possible to bind the selected value together "across" the ng-include scopes ? Plus, the value is not present in the controller. [Example](http://jsbin.com/IKuHAga/6/edit?html,js,output) - maybe theuse of template here is wrong ? .

Comment: Try using a directive for this. Maybe this [blog post](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/) helps? I would try to use `ngRepeat` for the dynamic change you mentioned. Maybe I can get an example working...

Comment: @haki Sorry, couldn't get it running like that. It seems nested `ngRepeat` don't work (my broken [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4d7p/)). Maybe you consider not to use recoursion?

Comment: how would you do that if the depth are un even ?

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/U4d7p/4/) for example. There is only one array for ngRepeat and each `select` knows its "depth"-index (simply the `$index` of `ngRepeat`). If a value is selected, all "deeper" array elements are removed and the one with the current "depth" is changed. This solution isn't very pretty either but I can't see how to do this better.

Comment: Thanks man - This excatly what I wanted. i added a few stuff of my own [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U4d7p/6/). Update you answer and i'll accept it.